# Http Post Image data in C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, http-post

I have implemented a Restful web service in C# .Net and I want to enable users to upload images via this.

What I currently have is a service that only accepts text data. Ideally I need to get an image from the user and store it in my database.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/{key}", Method = "POST")]
ResponseStatus InsertSensor(string key, Image image);
```

My question what is the most efficient way to do this?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image is not something you can transmit down a wire.

Instead, you need to *encode* the image into a stream or byte array (probably using PNG or JPEG).

The client would then send these bytes to the server, and the server would store it in the database.

Comment: What are the recommended ways to encode an image can I use XML?

Comment: @DafaDil: XML is a very inefficient way to encode an image.  You are probably familiar with existing standard image encodings, such as PNG, GIF, or JPEG.  Note that each one has its strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: What do we need to pass when calling the service? is it the image path? Ex: - serviceAPi/10/c:/Images/image1.jpg, and what is the type of the input parameter?

Comment: @DafaDil: The web service has no access to your client disk.  You need to pass the actual bytes as a POST payload.

Comment: So it would be something like a byte[] buffer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29609/discussion-between-dafadil-and-slaks)

Answer (score 1):

Sample project from MSDN: [ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-File-Upload-a8c0fb0d/view/SourceCode#content)

Here's another write-up that might be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: What do we need to pass when calling the service? is it the image path? Ex: - serviceAPi/10/c:/Images/image1.jpg, and what is the type of the input parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You could allow the users to post the image to a http handler as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349146/how-to-post-a-binary-image-from-desktop-app-to-ashx-handler-and-receive-it).

Comment: What do we need to pass when calling the service? is it the image path? Ex: - serviceAPi/10/c:/Images/image1.jpg, and what is the type of the input parameter?